# Prevent initialization of Hibernate Search in Spring application

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

I have a Model class which is shared between two applications. One of the application needs to support full text search which has been implemented using [hibernate search](http://hibernate.org/search/). The other application does not need this search capability. The problem is that when I startup my spring application the index directories are created automatically. Is there any way I can prevent these index directories from being created in the other application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Hibernate Search 6+, set the configuration property `hibernate.search.enabled` to `false` for the application you don't want to use Hibernate Search in.

In Hibernate Search 5, set the configuration property `hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners` to `false` for the application you don't want to use Hibernate Search in.

Source: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-configuration-event